# "On your keyboard, idiot!" - clickable scolding <kbd>s

Tags: script, bookmarklet

### Screenshot

[image]

### About

July 2, 2009. [Complaints are raised on Meta Stack Overflow over the styling of `<kbd>` tags.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1939/223030) One helpful commenter humorously suggested that

> Now all they need is an onclick handler to make them look like you are pressing them. Then an alert box pops up and says "On your keyboard, idiot!".

This is what this script does.

#### What about links?

Putting links in `<kbd>`s (or `<kbd>`s in links) is generally a Bad Idea. However, it happens, and sometimes you want to click them. To compensate for this, any `<kbd>` that contains a link or is contained directly within one will not trigger an alert.

#### License

[**The MIT License**](http://opensource.org/licenses/MIT)

#### Download

[**Userscript**](https://gist.github.com/michaelb958/8927839/raw/333e1faea6030fe45a0a8f11a43906f246a517b6/kbd.user.js)

Or copy and paste this into a bookmarklet:

```
javascript:$('<style type="text/css">').text('kbd:hover{border-style:outset}kbd:active{border-style:inset}').appendTo(document.head);$(document).on('click','*:not(a)>kbd:not(:has(a))',function(){alert("On your keyboard, idiot!");});void(0)
```

#### Platform

Runs on any browser that jQuery supports (which is quite a few).

### Contact

It's just me, [@michaelb958](https://stackexchange.com/users/1048581/michaelb958?tab=accounts). You can contact me by:

- Commenting on or answering this post. This is the preferred mechanism for providing feedback or suggestions.
- Pinging me on [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/). For general conversation and stuff.
- Emailing me (email address available on [my GitHub profile](https://github.com/michaelb958)). For use in case of emergency.

### Code

jQuery, with a dash of JavaScript.
[Github Gist!](https://gist.github.com/michaelb958/8927839)

Comment: If you're using a browser that doesn't support jQuery... you should *totally* drop that and try jQuery.